# How to fix “Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js)”

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, postcss-loader

I'm getting this error when I try to run my app, I'm using all the same dependencies that I always use so I'm very baffled by this.

> Warn in
>
> in ./assets/css/style.css
>
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> (13:3) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start
> instead
> friendly-errors 18:06:28  @ ./assets/css/style.css   @ ./.nuxt/App.js
> @ ./.nuxt/index.js  @ ./.nuxt/client.js  @ multi eventsource-polyfill
> webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client
> ./.nuxt/client.js

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
build: {
    postcss: {
      preset: {
        features: {
          // Fixes: https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/1190#issuecomment-546621554
          "focus-within-pseudo-class": false
        }
      },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this warn:

`start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead`

> Although the warning message can be ignored,but it makes me unwell.

finally, i find a reasonable answer [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), the point is `flex-direction` vs `writing-mode direction`

```js
1. flex-start (default): items are packed toward the start of the flex-direction.
2. flex-end: items are packed toward the end of the flex-direction.
3. start: items are packed toward the start of the writing-mode direction.
4. end: items are packed toward the end of the writing-mode direction.
```